# How to properly say "Finally, I'd like to thank..:" at the end of a speech?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm holding my first speech in Japanese tomorrow. Most of it is set and done, the only thing I have a bit difficulty translating properly is how to say "Finally, I'd like to thank *name*-sensei (my Japanese teacher) for teaching me Japanese." at the end.

I hope there is someone who can help a lost soul. 
Thank you very much!

*Currently I've got something like "Saigo ni, watashi wa *name*-sensei ni kansha shimasu." but I feel it doesn't really fit as a proper ending... (it doesn't have the right "tone", doesn't seem like it ends the speech.)

Answer (score 1):

「最後に、私に日本語を教えてくださっている、"your teacher's name"先生にお礼を申しあげます。」

Saigo-ni watashi-ni nihongo-o oshiete kudasatte iru "your teacher's name" sensei-ni orei-o moushi agemasu.

If your teacher no longer teaches you, you should say

日本語を教えてくださった (past tense)
 (nihongo-o oshiete kudasatta)

I hope this makes it in time.